# jump destination too far : by 3 byte(s)

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I m having a problem with my loop, the code contained in it is long and it gives me error `jump destination too far : by 3 byte(s)`. When ı remove:

```
mov edx,offset str1 
call writestring
```

this part below the main PROC, it doesnt give an error. But ı need this string user enters a negative number to give a message. How can ı?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

    money      dword    200,100,50,20,10,5,1
    str1       byte     "Enter the amounts for each value of money : ",0
    str2       byte     "The sum of your moneys are:",0
    total      dword    0
    buffer     dword    1000 dup(0),0    
    str3       byte     "Do not enter neg number ",0

.code
main PROC
    mov edx,offset str1 
    call writestring
    call crlf
    mov ecx,lengthof money
    mov esi,0
    mov edi,0

start1:
    jmp continue
    don:
    push ecx


    mov edx,ecx
    mov edx,0

    mov edx,7
    sub edx,ecx
    mov ecx,edx
    mov edi,0
    mov esi,0
        start2:

            mov eax,money[esi]
            call writedec
            mov ebx,eax
            mov al,'x'
            call writechar
            mov eax,buffer[edi]
            call writedec
            call crlf
            add esi,4 
            add edi,4

        loop start2

    pop ecx
    continue:

    ;**************************************************
    mov edx,0
    mov eax,money[esi]
    call writedec
    mov ebx,eax
    mov al,'x'
    call writechar
    call readint
    ;***************************************************

    sub eax,0
    js don
    mov buffer[edi],eax
    ;*************************
    mul ebx
    add total,eax       ;we add each the multiplication to total.
    add esi,4           ;increases the index by 4.(because of dword type)
    add edi,4


loop start1

    mov edx,offset str2
    call writestring
    mov eax, total
    call writedec

    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: What instruction does the error refer to?

Comment: mov edx,offset str1 call writestring

Comment: Your code is a great example of why you should never use the LOOP instruction.

Comment: for what reason is this code an example of never using loops

Comment: I agree with Ross. Loop has performance implication but is limited in range in branching back 128 bytes or forward 127. If you changed all the `mov reg, 0` to `xor reg, reg` to zero a register then you might have just enough room to fit everything. If you want to keep loop you have to reduce the number of bytes inside the loop.

Comment: You should never LOOP because it's 1) slower than the alternative 2) only allows a limited jump range 3) doesn't support nested loops without having save/restore ECX, making it even slower.

Comment: @RossRidge in a bootloader (clearly not the case here) I think `loop` could be acceptable if pressed for space.

Answer (score 1):

`loop` has limited range. It can only jump up to 127 bytes ahead or 128 back in the instruction stream measured from the start of the following instruction.

To get around that, you can do something like the following.

Instead of

```
label1:

<lots of code>

loop label1
```

if the label is out of reach you can do something like this:

```
label1:

<lots of code>

loop tmp1
jmp tmp2
tmp1:
  jmp label1
tmp2:
```

or else use a different construct based on conditional jumps that don't have the range limitation.

Comment: Thank you so much. Well is error depending on the type of jump instruction for example js? Or do ı need just putting labels?

Comment: `js` and the other conditional jumps _used_ to have this same limitations on early x86 models, but now since forever there's been two variants of those where one has a signed 32-bit branch range. Most assemblers automatically pick the right jump size just from the mnemonic.

Comment: Why not just show `dec ecx / jnz label1` as the alternative, instead of that horrible hard-to-read construct with LOOP and JMP?  BTW, JCC rel32 was supported at least as early as 386, so you never need to avoid it in 32-bit code.

Comment: There's one more way to avoid that error... putting "lot of code" into subroutines, so then `label1:`  `call lots_of_code_in_subroutine`  `loop label1` would work. But doing `dec ecx` `jnz label1` is more efficient. Still splitting large block of code into subroutines may have code clarity benefit, making it easier to debug and modify it.